# input box using jquery dropdown box

Tags: jquery

When a user types in my input field, I would like the div to appear or hide, in the same way as happens on google.com. In my case, when the user types 'ca', 'app' or 'ba' the values should appear. How do I do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the [jquery autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) plugin.